# Iteratively adding function output to a tibble in R

Tags: r, dataframe, iteration, purrr, tibble

I have a function in R which takes a Participant ID as input and outputs a dataframe with just one row and 10 columns. To call the function all I need to do is `function(id)` and I get:

| column1 | column2 | etc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| value | value | etc |

I want to run the function on every ID from a list of IDs and output a tibble with one row per participant where the first column is the ID number followed by all the normal columns from the function output, like so:

| ID | column1 | column2 | etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | value | value | etc |
| 02 | value | value | etc |
| 03 | value | value | etc |

My instinct (as an inexperienced R user) is to try and do this in a `for` loop but I assume there will be a better way to do it with `purrr`. Is `map_df` what I want here? And how do I add the extra column for Participant ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using `map_df` would help by specifying the `.id` argument.

```
fn <- function(id) {
  #some function that returns a dataframe
}

#If your dataframe is called `df` with `ID` column in it
result <- purrr::map_df(df$ID, fn, .id = 'ID')
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `rbindlist`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(df$ID, fn), idcol = "ID")
```